# Can't enhance kodo JPA classes

Tags: jpa, ant

I am just moving to Kodo JPA version 4.2 and it isn't going smoothly.

when I run my any build script (in eclipse 3.4.1) I get

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\My Documents\eclipseWorkspaces\cnmp e341\blue ebig\ebig\src\java\build.xml:91: <openjpa-1.1.0-r422266:657916 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: MetaDataFactory could not be configured (conf.newMetaDataFactoryInstance() returned null). This might mean that no configuration properties were found. Ensure that you have a META-INF/persistence.xml file, that it is available in your classpath, or that the properties file you are using for configuration is available. If you are using Ant, please see the <properties> or <propertiesFile> attributes of the task's nested <config> element. This can also occur if your OpenJPA distribution jars are corrupt, or if your security policy is overly strict.
```

My build.xml is sitting in my java directory next to my META-INF directory containing my persistence.xml file

here is the snippet from the build.xml

```
<target name="enhance">
    <echo>base dir is ${basedir}</echo>
  <!-- define the kodoc task; this can be done at the top of the    -->
  <!-- build.xml file, so it will be available for all targets      -->
  <taskdef name="kodoc" classname="kodo.ant.PCEnhancerTask"/>

  <!-- invoke enhancer on all .jdo files below the current directory -->
  <kodoc>
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/jpa/*.java" />
        <include name="**/jpa/*.class" />
    </fileset>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${basedir}"/>
    </classpath>
  </kodoc>
</target>
```

The entity class files are in the jpa directory. So the directory structure looks like this:

```
+ top
  + src
    + java
    | + com
    |   + splat
    |   | + jpa
    |   |   - entity.java 
    |   | + stuff
    |       - Object.java
    | + META-INF
    |   - persistence.xml
      - build.xml
```

I had thought I had followed the directions in the doc., but clearly I didn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed by adding config propertiesFile="../../config/ebig.kodo.properties"/>
to the task it now looks like

```
  <kodoc>
    <config propertiesFile="../../config/ebig.kodo.properties"/>
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/jpa/*.java" />
        <include name="**/jpa/*.class" />
    </fileset>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${basedir}"/>
    </classpath>
  </kodoc>
```

Comment: What do you have in your `ebig.kodo.properties` ?

Comment: I no longer know what was in ebig.kodo.properties. The project went in another direction.